# Google Chart Tooltip allignment issue

Tags: jquery, charts, tooltip, google-visualization

I have displayed the pie chart using google chart. But the tool-tip is having alignment issue. I have looked for the solution but i could not get any solution for that. This is my code

```
function drawChart() {

        var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dt.addColumn('date', 'Test Date');
        dt.addColumn('number', 'Total Correct');

        dt.addRows([
        <?php $val_counter = 1; 
           foreach($vals as $row):?>
            [new Date(<?=date('Y', strtotime($row->date_administered))?>, <?=date('n', strtotime($row->date_administered))-1?>, <?=date('j', strtotime($row->date_administered))?>), <?=$row->total_score?>]<?if($val_counter < count($vals)):?>,<?endif;?>
        <?php $val_counter++;
           endforeach; ?>
        ]);

        var dv = new google.visualization.DataView(dt);
        dv.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type:'string'}, 1]);

        var options = {
          title: '<?=$chartData['val_title']?>',
          pointSize: 8,
          interpolateNulls: true,
          chartArea: { width: 300 },
          legend: { position: 'bottom'},
          hAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: new Date(<?=$start_date[0]?>, <?=$start_date[1]-1?>, <?=$start_date[2]?>),
                max: new Date(<?=$end_date[0]?>, <?=$end_date[1]-1?>, <?=$end_date[2]?>)
            },
            //format:'M/d/y',
            slantedText: false,
            maxAlternation: 1
          },
          vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: <?=$chartData['val_vert_axis_min_range']?>,
                max: <?=$chartData['val_vert_axis_max_range']?>
            }
          },
          series: [
                {color: '#CC9933'}
            ]
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('draw_chart'));
        chart.draw(dv, options);
      }
```

And this is issue i'm facing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its my mistake only, a simple option solved this issue. I have added

```
tooltip: { isHtml: true },
```

in the options variable. Now it is showing the tool-tip without alignment issue